# World Wide Call Forwarding Codes

Tags: android, call

I'm wondering if anybody knows where I can find a compilation of call forwarding codes by country and carrier. For example, according to the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_forwarding to activate conditional call forwarding when busy

- on most GSM Networks you can use *67*[number]#
- in North America most carriers use *68[number]
- Sprint Nextel uses *74[number]
- and I'm sure there are more variations depending on where you are

So my question again, is there a full list of all these codes available out there, or even better, an android library that handles these scenarios? :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplementary_service_codes

Follow 3gpp specification link for details:
http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/22030.htm

last contains references to other codes as well.

These codes where created for old mobiles phones when BSSAP (mobile - network signaling) did not include signaling messages to handle SS state/data change. Later these were included into specifications, but people still use them. Memory effect ...